# "if any dog could talk" vs "any dogs who could talk"

Tags: comparison

I wonder whether the two sentences below are interchangeable.

i)  If any dog could talk, it would be the dog that communicates with people.

ii) Any dog who could talk would be the dog that communicates with people.

Besides one being conditional and not so for the other. Is there any other difference in their implication or tone?

Thank you very much,

Comment: It's a bizarre context, but the definite article in ***the** dog* would by default be interpreted very differently in these two examples. The first one implies *no matter which specific dog we're referring to (there might be many talking dogs), **that dog** would communicate with people (rather than **people** communicating with the dog)*. The second version implies *There **is** a dog (but only one) that communicates with people. Possible there are no dogs that can talk, but if there **was** a talking dog, it would be **that "communicating" dog just referred to**.*

Comment: As F-F notes, it's a bizarre context.  This kind of context makes me think that you are really asking about a general point, or have a different specific example, which you choose not to tell us about.  Perhaps this is a simplified example. If you have some other expression in mind, it is best to ask about that, rather than make up a new context.